# how to test $scope.method inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I've tried using Spies, tried declaring a variable by calling the function and nothing works.I 'm new to unit testing and i must be misunderstanding something

my unit test for the function

```
   describe('search treatments method',function(){
  it('search treament should have been called',function(){
      testSearch = new scope.searchTreatments();
      spyOn(testSearch,'searchTreatments');
      expect(testSearch.searchTreatments).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

the method i wanna test

```
  $scope.searchTreatments = function(value){
    return Treatment.find(value).then(function(values){
      return values;
    });
  };
```

treatment is a factory in another file

```
  app.factory('Treatment',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){
function _getTreatment(val) {
  return $http.get('/api/providers_medical_services_services', {
    params: {
      type: 'treatment',
      treatment: val
    }
  }).then(function(response){
    return response.data;
  });
}
return {
  find: _getTreatment
};
}]);
```

Basically, I just want to create a spy on testsearch to see if its called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mock the factory, if i am not wrong.

You must probably use angular-mocks.js inorder to mock a service or a factory in order to be tested in Karma

Also check your karma.config, if you have added your Controller and Services files.

-Thanks

Comment: i addded all controllers and services. What do you mean by mock? I see this term floating around and i dont understand it

Comment: Mock is something like u create a mock service, a service or a factory within your test case that can emulate primary functionalities of that service. You have to then inject them into your test case controller Visit : http://tech.pro/tutorial/1517/supplying-mocks-for-services-via-provide